# Dockerfile setup for an Arch Linux based remote desktop

Tags: docker, archlinux, remote-desktop

I am struggeling to get the following desired setup to work:

- Arch based system (lightweight) for a remote desktop
- Using RDP, so I can log in from practically any windows machine
- Any windowmanager whatsoever (at this stage I literally do not care any more, as long as it works). xfce4 is what I explored most extensively, but really, it doesnt matter.
- Dockerfile (or YAML/docker-compose)

I have failed in more ways than I can count at this. Used google searches, bing.chat and chatGPT to no avail. My best result so far is a system which runs ("docker run -it ..."), allows a login via xrdp with the specified user - but then fails to load a desktop environment. (This includes figuring out hot to install xrdp in the first place.)

Here goes:

```
# Use the official Arch Linux base image
FROM archlinux:latest

# Update the package repository and install necessary packages
RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm && pacman -S --noconfirm \
    xorg-server \
    xorg-xinit \
    xterm \
    sed \
    sudo

# Get Requirements for building xrdp
RUN pacman -S --noconfirm git base-devel nasm check fuse libfdk-aac ffmpeg imlib2

# Now make temp user to install - root won't be allowed to 
RUN useradd -m -p $(echo "installnow" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) installer

# Switch to installer and change into installers home directory
USER installer
WORKDIR /home/installer

# Get yay change into yay dir and make package
RUN git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/xrdp.git
WORKDIR xrdp
RUN makepkg 

# Switch back to root for installation
USER root
WORKDIR /home/installer/xrdp

# have to install built package using pacman - because installation will fail without privileges (duh)
RUN pacman -U --noconfirm *.tar.zst

# Make sure xrdp uses 0.0.0.0 instead of default 127.0.0.1
RUN sed -i 's/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini

# Generate a random 16-character alphanumeric password for root
RUN root_password=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 16) && \
    echo "root:${root_password}" | chpasswd

# Add a dedicated user and set a password
RUN useradd -m rduser
RUN echo "rduser:secret12345" | chpasswd
RUN usermod -aG wheel rduser

# Create an Xinitrc file for starting the Xorg session
RUN echo "exec startxfce4" > /home/rduser/.xinitrc

# Set permissions for the rduser user
RUN chown rduser:rduser /home/rduser/.xinitrc

# Expose the RDP port (3389)
EXPOSE 3389

# Start xRDP and Xorg when the container runs
CMD ["xrdp", "-n"]
```

Any one have an idea how to get this working?

I am assuming my troubles should be more or less easily reproducable with this Dockerfile, but just in case. Host system is a strato VPS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04                                                           
Codename:       jammy

5.15.0-83-generic x86_64
```

Best, JoW

Comment: Up until the last bullet point, the setup you describe sounds exactly like a virtual machine, and I might use that technology instead.  A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process and getting it to simulate a full desktop environment can be tricky.

Comment: Hey David thanks for your suggestion! Admittedly I completely overlooked the possibility to use VMs - mainly since my use case is more or less one of "disposeable systems" and I am under the impression, docker containers should be more lightweight than VMs. (Obviously does not take away from the fact, that basic functioning ranks way higher than ressource-saving-approaches). So I'll give VMs a go.

Nontheless: I am basically "tickled" and sort of hell bent on getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative to using arch: debian slim in current release.

Following Dockerfile generates a working system:

```
# Use the official Debian "bookworm-slim" base image
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

# Set environment variables to avoid interactive prompts during installation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Generate a random 16-character alphanumeric password for root
RUN echo root:$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 16) | chpasswd

# Update the package repository and install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    xrdp \
    mate-desktop-environment-core \
    falkon

# Add a dedicated user and set a password
RUN useradd -m user
RUN echo "user:userpassword" | chpasswd
RUN usermod -aG sudo user

# Configure xRDP to use MATE as the default session
RUN echo mate-session > /home/user/.xsession

# Set up permissions for the user
RUN chown user:user -R /home/user

# Expose the RDP port (3389)
EXPOSE 3389

# Start xRDP when the container runs
CMD service xrdp start && /bin/bash
```